# How to count and order correctly result from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have like this task currently:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag_converted` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - not converted, 1 - converted',
  `flag_error` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - no errors, 1 - error occurred',
  `rating` INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1-5',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 0, 5);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 0, 5);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (NULL, 0, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (1, 0, 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (1, 1, 0, 5);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (2, 0, 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (3, 1, 0, 5);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (3, 1, 0, 5);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (4, 0, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (4, 0, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (4, 0, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `files` (`id_user`, `flag_converted`, `flag_error`, `rating`) VALUES (4, 0, 1, 2);
```

(sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/431723/49/0)

It is necessary to form a SQL query to the files table which displays the number of files based on the success of the conversion and the presence of a good rating from registered / unregistered users.

Output format:

`user_type` ('Visitor' if id_user = NULL; 'User' otherwise),

`flag_converted`,

`is_best_rating` ('1' - if rating = 5; '0' otherwise),

`count` (number of records).

The results must be sorted by `count` and `is_best_rating` in reverse order. And display only groups where `count` is greater than 1.

My current query:

```
SELECT id, flag_converted, CASE
    WHEN rating = 5 THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS is_best_rating, CASE
    WHEN id_user IS NULL THEN 'Visitor'
    ELSE 'User'
END AS user_type from files
```

In my task says:

> The results must be sorted by `count`

Where I can get value of `count` correctly in this case and sort?

Comment: AFAIK the query you posted above won't generate that error message.  Are you certain that you posted the correct query?

Comment: My query is correct but where I must get value of `count` field I dont now curretly from task description @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Re-read the above comment.  The query you posted can't generate this error message.

Comment: Help us understand here, the result that you're getting from the query, is it correct? And what you're looking for is to order them according to `count`?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the task then? It's just that I don't understand what exactly is required, meaning: "The results must be sorted by count and is_best_rating in reverse order. " @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I just wrote a query to the table based on my level of understanding of the task

Comment: If you want to SUMMARIZE  your table with a count, you need to ad a Group By clause to your query to tell it what to count.

Comment: `count (number of records)` needs to define how the rows must be divided to groups for to count the rows. For example, it can be "a group includes the files which have the same is_best_rating and user_type  values".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, according to the task requirement, you'll need to return 4 columns `user_type`,`flag_converted`,`is_best_rating` and `count` with specific `CASE` or `IF` condition on the `id_user` and `rating`. Your current query seems to met most of those conditions but let's try to follow the tasks requirement. First, change the columns in `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN id_user IS NULL THEN 'Visitor'
    ELSE 'User'
END AS user_type,
flag_converted,
CASE
    WHEN rating = 5 THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS is_best_rating,
COUNT(*) AS count
...
```

Since we're adding `COUNT()` which is an aggregation, we need to modify the query with a `GROUP BY`. So all three other columns in `SELECT` except for `count` must be added to the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN id_user IS NULL THEN 'Visitor'
    ELSE 'User'
END AS user_type,
flag_converted,
CASE
    WHEN rating = 5 THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS is_best_rating, COUNT(*) AS count 
from files
GROUP BY user_type, flag_converted, is_best_rating
```

And for this condition *"The results must be sorted by `count` and `is_best_rating` in **reverse order**. And display only groups where count is greater than 1."*. You probably can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN id_user IS NULL THEN 'Visitor'
    ELSE 'User'
END AS user_type,
flag_converted,
CASE
    WHEN rating = 5 THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS is_best_rating, COUNT(*) AS count 
from files
GROUP BY user_type, flag_converted, is_best_rating
HAVING count > 1
ORDER BY count DESC, is_best_rating DESC;
```

I think *reverse order* means the largest value first so `ORDER BY xxx DESC` is making sure of that. As for `HAVING count > 1` its self-explanatory but with or without it, I don't see any `count=1`; kind of make me think that I might've missed something.

Anyway [here's your updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/431723/64)